# Custom limit categories list wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, limit

Lately I'm working on wordpress and I have a design somewhat complicated and can not find a function in wordpress especially to print the categories as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Category 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">More Categories</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Category 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Category 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Category 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Category 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code should work on the list of the wordpress post. Taking the forech of wordpress

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a><li>';
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Comment: Your link points to `get_the_category_list()`, yet your code uses `get_the_category()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, just correct.

Comment: What's the logic behind displaying a post's categories like that? Which categories should go in the first level `<ul>` and which in the second? Also, where should `More Categories` point at?

Comment: A list of parent categories from 1 to to 7, just for the theme design I have to keep only 3 and then the other with a "more categories". I'm not really programmer if someone help me would be great :)

Comment: [Not a programming question:] Which 3? What's the criteria?

Comment: Only show the first 3 categories and then the other categories into a "more categories" (in case we have like 10 categories by post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$hasmore=false;
$i=0;
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
  if($i==3)
    {
    $hasmore=true;
    echo '<li><a href="UnansweredCommentQuestion.php">More Categories</a><ul>';
    }
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a></li>';
  $i++;
}
if($hasmore) echo "</ul></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below function

```
wp_list_categories()
```

Comment: Do not think it works this because what is required to go inside the wordpress loop but personalized way to show only the first 3 categories and the other on a "more categories"

Comment: Do you created a parent - sub categories in backend?